# Cell - surface intersection

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have a mesh that consists of cells (Voronoi cell). Cells have arbitrary count of faces. I want to intersect this cells with border (closed surface, that consists of triangles). I want the vertices of the border to also be part of the clipped cell. It turned out to be difficult to do. What algorithms exist for this?

Comment: What do you mean by the border consists of triangles (rather than a polygonal boundary)?

Comment: Border is a surface. I have set of linked triangles, which are surface discretization.